# Three-digit post scores displaying wrong in sidebar

Tags: bug, related-questions, linked-questions

The new MSE is line-breaking where it shouldn't. Specifically, the Related and Linked questions sections are breaking in the middle of post counts that are more than two digits long.

[image: Image with red freehand circles!]

System Info: Win7, IE11, no toolbars, no add-ons, no userscripts, etc.

Comment: Yay, my first MSE VTC-as-dupe.

Comment: Pah! I've been trying to keep on top of all the bugs, to avoid that. Ah well.