# Bug in the look of side bar- 4 digit post score is not fitting in the box but 3 digits are fitting correctly

Tags: bug, design, score, sidebar

I know some related [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229771/three-digit-post-scores-displaying-wrong-in-sidebar) have been asked before but all are 3 digit score related and in my question, three digit scores are correctly fitting in the side bar but 4 digit scores are not fitting and it exceeding the box. Why we can't fix this bug?

[image]